# How to find Latest records and set the value in different column if same name having multiple records

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am trying to get the `State` based on `Version` column but not able to get the desired result. If same `Name` record having Latest `Version` then the `State` Should be `SIGNED` otherwise it should be `SUPERSEDED`.

```
Name    Version State       OwnerName   Language    Keywords
Mohan   1       SUPERSEDED  x           ENG         ABCD
Mohan   2       SUPERSEDED  y           ENG         EFGH
Mohan   3       SUPERSEDED  z           ENG         IJKL
Mohan   4       SIGNED      x           ENG         ABCD
Shayam  1       SUPERSEDED  y           ENG         EFGH
Shayam  2       SIGNED      z           ENG         IJKL
Ram     1       SUPERSEDED  x           ENG         ABCD
Ram     2       SIGNED      y           ENG         EFGH
Sourabh 1       SIGNED      z           ENG         IJKL
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this array formula:

```
=IF(B2=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$10=A2,$B$2:$B$10)),"SIGNED","SUPERSEDED")
```

Put this in C2.

Then because it is an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then copy down.

[image]

---

If you have Excel 2010 or later then you can use this non CSE formula.  It does not require the Ctrl-Shift-Enter, but is entered normally:

```
=IF(B2=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$10/($A$2:$A$10=A2),1),"SIGNED","SUPERSEDED")
```

[image]

---

If your data is always sorted on columns A and B then you can use a non array formula:

```
=IF(A2<>A3,"SIGNED","SUPERSEDED")
```

[image]